# Dynamic matrix as a static parameter of a function

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, declaration, allocation

Basically, I want to create a dynamic matrix and create a function that receives the matrix in a static form of `matrix[rows][cols]`.
Things work great when the function receives matrix in the form of `*matrix[const]`, but that's "half dynamic".

I am aware that when I declare `int **matrix`, for example, and allocate memory, then I create a pointer that points to an array of pointers... and when I declare the matrix in the static form at the header of the function, then I don't really receive the data, but the pointers addresses. 
 So, there is any way to create a complete dynamic matrix and send it as a complete static matrix?

Comment: Be aware of that `*matrix[const]` is an array of pointers. An array of arrays decays to a pointer to arrays (e.g. `(*matrix)[const]`).

Answer (score 1):

Since C supports [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (which I think you mean you use) you can also use them when calling functions. Just pass the dimensions as arguments first, and use them for the array or matrix argument that follows:

```
void some_function(size_t rows, size_t cols, int matrix[rows][cols])
{
    ...
}
```

Note that `matrix` in the above functoin will actually be a *pointer*. The compiler will see the argument declaration `int matrix[rows][cols]` as `int (*matrix)[cols]`.

Comment: I understand what you say, but it ain't working yet. it has red underlines says "a parameter is not allowed".

Comment: @OfekPintok Okay, then it's time for you to edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as the full and complete build error (as text). Also tell us what compiler you're using, what version of the compiler, and any flags or settings you use when building.

Comment: @OfekPintok You must be using C99 or higher; this is not allowed in C89. What version are you using?

Comment: @AlexQuilliam I'm using Visual Studio 2015, so yeah, I think that goes for C99.

Comment: @OfekPintok VS2015 should have implemented most of C99 in regards to the language itself. But without an MCVE and the complete and full error it's hard to say what the problem is. Please post a new question about it, including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the copy-pasted (in full and complete) error output (as text).

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports Variable Length Arrays then you can use them for your task.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init( size_t, size_t, int matrix[*][*] );
void display( size_t, size_t, int matrix[*][*] );

void init( size_t rows, size_t cols, int matrix[rows][cols] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            matrix[i][j] = i * cols + j;
        }
    }
}

void display( size_t rows, size_t cols, int matrix[rows][cols] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%3d ", matrix[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}


int main(void) 
{
    size_t rows, cols;

    printf( "Enter number of rows: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &rows );

    printf( "Enter number of cols: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &cols );

    int ( *matrix )[cols] = malloc( sizeof( int[rows][cols] ) );

    init( rows, cols, matrix );
    display( rows, cols, matrix );

    free( matrix );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look

```
Enter number of rows: 3
Enter number of cols: 4
  0   1   2   3 
  4   5   6   7 
  8   9  10  11
```

Or without the dynamic allocation the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

void init( size_t, size_t, int matrix[*][*] );
void display( size_t, size_t, int matrix[*][*] );

void init( size_t rows, size_t cols, int matrix[rows][cols] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            matrix[i][j] = i * cols + j;
        }
    }
}

void display( size_t rows, size_t cols, int matrix[rows][cols] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%3d ", matrix[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}


int main(void) 
{
    size_t rows, cols;

    printf( "Enter number of rows: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &rows );

    printf( "Enter number of cols: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &cols );

    int matrix[rows][cols];

    init( rows, cols, matrix );
    display( rows, cols, matrix );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look as shown above.

Otherwise you indeed need to allocate dynamically a one dimensional array of pointers and one dimensional arrays that are referred by the pointers.

Comment: My compiler doesn't support it. I did allocate the memory this way, but when I set the function as ' matrix[const][const] ' it doesn't run well and prints the addresses of the pointers instead of the data.

Comment: @OfekPintok const is a reserved word. You should use any other identifier And at last try my examples. Do you have a problem with them?

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean that I write "const", but I use a constant value by declaring #define and put it inside the brackets.

Comment: @OfekPintok Did you try my examples?

Comment: yeah, and I get red underlines.

Comment: @OfekPintok If you copied and pasted my examples as is then your compiler does not support variable length arrays.